# Build list of directories and files to website

Tags: python, html, tree

This may or may not be an easy one for someone out there...

I'm trying to build a file restore service. I have a dictionary that looks like this.

```
{'full_path': '/home/michael/Data',
 'items': {'UpgradeToCentOS5': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/UpgradeToCentOS5',
                                'type': 'f',
                                'versions': ['current', '09/10/12']},
           'basic_debian': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/basic_debian',
                            'type': 'f',
                            'versions': ['current']},
           'deploy.tgz': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/deploy.tgz',
                          'type': 'f',
                          'versions': ['current']},
           'firewall': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/firewall',
                        'type': 'f',
                        'versions': ['current']},
           'legalholder.sh': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/legalholder.sh',
                              'type': 'f',
                              'versions': ['current']},
           'lists': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists',
                     'items': {'boothosts': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/boothosts',
                                             'type': 'f',
                                             'versions': ['current']},
                               'checklist': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/checklist',
                                             'type': 'f',
                                             'versions': ['current']},
                               'ns_ip': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/ns_ip',
                                         'type': 'f',
                                         'versions': ['current']},
                               'server_info': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/server_info',
                                               'type': 'f',
                                               'versions': ['current']},
                               'temp': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/temp',
                                        'type': 'f',
                                        'versions': ['current']},
                               'tsm_clients': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/tsm_clients',
                                               'type': 'f',
                                               'versions': ['current']}},
                     'type': 'd',
                     'versions': ['current']},
           'salt': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/salt',
                    'type': 'f',
                    'versions': ['current']},
           'std-srv': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/std-srv',
                       'type': 'f',
                       'versions': ['current']},
           'upgrade_debian_6': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/upgrade_debian_6',
                                'type': 'f',
                                'versions': ['current']},
           'using-imaps': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/using-imaps',
                           'type': 'f',
                           'versions': ['current']},
           'xiv_online_resize': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/xiv_online_resize',
                                 'type': 'f',
                                 'versions': ['current']}},
 'type': 'd',
 'versions': ['current']}
```

Basically... it's a dictionary for data I find that can be recovered. All files (not sure about directories) will have 'versions' which is a list of versions that exist for that file.

I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to turn this into HTML data that the user can use to select the version of the files they want to have restored. (limit is one version restoration per file.

I've never built anything like this and I'm not pulling up anything in searches.

Anything I'm missing in my details?

I /think/ what I'm looking for is something like this...

```
- home
-- /michael
--- /Data
---- UpgradeToCentOS5
      □ Version: current
      □ Version: 09/10/12
---- basic_debian
      □ Version: current
---- deploy.tgz
      □ Version: current
---- firewall
      □ Version: current
---- legalholder.sh
      □ Version: current
---- lists
----- boothosts
       □ Version: current
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to produce something like your example.

```
recovery = {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data',
 'items': {'UpgradeToCentOS5': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/UpgradeToCentOS5',
                                'type': 'f',
                                'versions': ['current', '09/10/12']},
           'basic_debian': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/basic_debian',
                            'type': 'f',
                            'versions': ['current']},
           'deploy.tgz': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/deploy.tgz',
                          'type': 'f',
                          'versions': ['current']},
           'firewall': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/firewall',
                        'type': 'f',
                        'versions': ['current']},
           'legalholder.sh': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/legalholder.sh',
                              'type': 'f',
                              'versions': ['current']},
           'lists': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists',
                     'items': {'boothosts': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/boothosts',
                                             'type': 'f',
                                             'versions': ['current']},
                               'checklist': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/checklist',
                                             'type': 'f',
                                             'versions': ['current']},
                               'ns_ip': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/ns_ip',
                                         'type': 'f',
                                         'versions': ['current']},
                               'server_info': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/server_info',
                                               'type': 'f',
                                               'versions': ['current']},
                               'temp': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/temp',
                                        'type': 'f',
                                        'versions': ['current']},
                               'tsm_clients': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/lists/tsm_clients',
                                               'type': 'f',
                                               'versions': ['current']}},
                     'type': 'd',
                     'versions': ['current']},
           'salt': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/salt',
                    'type': 'f',
                    'versions': ['current']},
           'std-srv': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/std-srv',
                       'type': 'f',
                       'versions': ['current']},
           'upgrade_debian_6': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/upgrade_debian_6',
                                'type': 'f',
                                'versions': ['current']},
           'using-imaps': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/using-imaps',
                           'type': 'f',
                           'versions': ['current']},
           'xiv_online_resize': {'full_path': '/home/michael/Data/xiv_online_resize',
                                 'type': 'f',
                                 'versions': ['current']}},
 'type': 'd',
 'versions': ['current']}

import os

def get_parent_dirs(path):
    parents = []
    x = path.split('/')[1:-1]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        parents.append('/'.join(x[0:i+1]))
    return parents

# Get a list of files and versions from the dictionary
items = []
pending = [recovery]
while pending:
    x = pending.pop(0)
    for item in x['items']:
        item = x['items'][item]
        if item.has_key('items'): # a directory
            pending.append(item)
        else: # a file
            items.append((item['full_path'], item['versions']))
items.sort()

parent_dirs = []
for path, versions in items:

    # Print parent directories if necessary
    for directory in get_parent_dirs(path):
        if not directory in parent_dirs:
            parent_dirs.append(directory)
            print '%s /%s' % (len(directory.split('/'))*'-', os.path.split(directory)[1])

    # Print file versions
    directory, filename = os.path.split(path)
    padding = len(path.split('/'))-1
    print '%s %s' % (padding*'-', filename)
    for version in versions:
        print '%s [] Version: %s' % (' '*padding, version)
```